# What are the proper ways to measure the distance between two adjacency matrices of two graphs

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces, algebraic-graph-theory

Suppose I have two undirected unweighted graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$, which have the same set of nodes. Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be their (binary) adjacency matrices, respectively.

I wonder what are the proper ways to quantitatively measure the similarity (or distance) between $G_1$ and $G_2$ (or specifically, $A_1$ and $A_2$).

For example, we can reshape $A_1$ and $A_2$ as vectors and measure the $p$-norm distance. I feel that there should be a correspondence between a **metric** and a **physical meaning** (e.g., how many edges we need to move to transform $G_1$ to $G_2$).

I wonder if there is some serious discussion (like papers) on measuring distances between graphs in graph theory literature.

Comment: Have you looked into graph isomorphism problem?

Comment: I'm no expert but a couple things: in the unweighted case, $p$-norm of the vector version would correspond to the Hamming distance, taken to the $1/p$ power. One should also be careful that presumably a metric would want to treat isomorphic graphs as the same, but graph isomorphism is not known to be efficiently solvable (might not be important to you though). Last, graphs are sometimes ``compared'' using the PSD ordering on the Laplacian.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brainstorm: in biological sequence analysis, there is a function called the "edit distance" that solves an analogous problem: e.g., how far apart are any 2 finite-length DNA sequences? This is defined in terms of the minimum number of "edits" required to convert one sequence into the other, using insertions and deletions.

Maybe we could define a type of "edit distance" for graphs, where we allow node and edge insertion/deletion operations, and count the minimum number of "graph edits" required to convert one graph to another?

Comment: Along these lines, there's something called a graph isomorphism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism

Comment: Perhaps more closely related to your answer: [Graph_edit_distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_edit_distance).